# Is there any part omitted in the following sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

The sentence is:

"*Despite its ability to hijack your senses and immerse you in hyper-realism, the real power of VR may lie in its ability to foster quiet intimacy **so realistic it’s unsettling**.*"

I'm really confused with this sentence. I think there is an omitted part after "realistic" or something else. I assume it should be "so realistic **that** it's unsettling" without omission, am I right?

Comment: Yes, either a word(may be that itself) or a phrase is missing.

Comment: Is it legitimate to omit it in this sentence?

Comment: Nothing is missing. A few things have been *elided*. But nothing is *missing*. And we are actually looking at two ellipses in rapid succession here: "quiet intimacy [that is] so realistic [that] it's unsettling". It is curious that you object to one but not the other, but rest assured they are both equally fine and indeed extremely common. So common, in fact, that "so X it's Y" has long become a [set phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_phrase) and inserting the *that* back in would make you sound weird at best, wrong at worst.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Hmm, well whether there's anything elided in your first example,s debatable. However, if there was it would be part of a relative clause, where the omission of *that* is subject to complex grammatical rules. However, the *that* in the second case would just be a marker of subordination in a content clause, which is why there are no rules involved, it can just be omitted regardless of the structure of the clause.